# Query Encryption Collection Field Maps Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, encryption

When an encrypted Collection is created using **clientEncryption.createEncryptedCollection** in Mongodb Atlas, an **"Encrypted Collection A"** is created from scratch following the **"Encrypted Fields Map A".**

I have **"Encypted Collection A"** with **"Encrypted Fields Map A"**. I want to modify several fields ( add encrypted fields, add regular unencrypted fields, remove some fields) inside of "Encrypted Collection A". How do I update/implement the **"Encrypted Fields Map A"** without having to create an entire new encrypted Collection?

Do I have to create a new Encrypted Collection every time I need to change the encrypted schema of the collection?

Comment: I don't remember all details, but I think after creating Encrypted collection. Next time when you will need this collection, you can simply use a regular approach to get it (the provided information is stored in the server). In the shell it will be just: `db.createdCollection.find(..)`. Don't know where exactly you want to call it, so convert this code to your language

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have to re-create the collection. Instead, you can update a field to be encrypted. I hope you will find this official [doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/queryable-encryption/fundamentals/encrypt-and-query/) useful.

Comment: I reached out to MongoDB support. They told me that when using Queryable Encryption it is not possible to add fields to an encrypted collection. The suggested work around is to create a new collection and copy the documents across.

Comment: Ahh! Have you tried what the docs say though?

Comment: Yes, I followed those docs when creating the collection. The docs don't mention updating a collection that has already been created